# Cannot destructure property as it is undefined. useContext error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont understand why does the below error keeps happening, so I could really use some help!

Error:

```
Login.jsx:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'user' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.
    at Login (Login.jsx:10:1)
```

Context.js:

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import Reducer from "./Reducer";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: null,
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
};

export const Context = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, INITIAL_STATE);

 

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value = {{
        user: state.user,
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        error: state.error,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Login.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Context } from '../../context/Context';
import './login.css';

export default function Login() {
  const userRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const { user, dispatch, isFetching } = useContext(Context); //error

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_START' });
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login`, {
        username: userRef.current.value,
        password: passwordRef.current.value,
      });
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE' });
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  console.log(user);
  return (
    <div className='login'>
      <span className='loginTitle'>Login</span>
      <form className='loginForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input
          type='text'
          className='loginInput'
          placeholder='Enter your username...'
          ref={userRef}
        />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          type='password'
          className='loginInput'
          placeholder='Enter your password...'
          ref={passwordRef}
        />
        <button className='loginButton' type='submit' disabled={isFetching}>
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
      <button className='loginRegisterButton'>
        <Link className='link' to='/register'>
          Register
        </Link>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you wrap your app in a `ContextProvider` component?

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap the parent of the Login component with the ContextProvider?

```
import { ContextProvider } from '../../context/Context';
import Login from "..."
function App() {

return(
  <>
    <ContextProvider>
      <Login>
      //any other child over here can access the context from this provider
    </ContextProvider>
  </>
 )
}
export default App;
```